# changing google map (map_canvas) size with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5

I have a google map on the page. It is positioned in the content area of the site (800px wide).

Now I added this code:

```
jQuery('#map_canvas').appendTo("body");
```

and also added a class with jQuery and changed the size to map_canvas so it is in FIXED position and 100% width and height (full screen).

All this works but the google map is not actually showing 100% width and height... here is how it shows - http://awesomescreenshot.com/00c1tiys3a

I noticed that IF I simply enter in Source Code (Google Chrome - inspect element(any element on page)), the google map shows normally 100% width and height... but it doesn't load from start normally 100% width and height.

I've done some researches but didn't quite find anything that could help me.

Comment: from previous experience you need to re-initialise the map after resizing it.

Comment: hmm.... can you give me a link to see how this can be done or maybe show me an example please?

Comment: There should be an `initialize()` function as seen in the following hello world example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#The_Hello_World_of_Google_Maps_v3 You need to run this function after you've resized the canvas.